# delete rows on listview and its values

Tags: android, listview, touch-event

I have a list view populate with numbers, and a edit text that sum the amount of numbers in the list view, I have written a implementation of ontouch, to delete rows in the list view, my question is: is there a way to delete the value that I delete in the list view on the edit text. for example if I delete the row 7 of 10 rows and its has a value of 5, and the amount is 35 display on the edit text, now the edit text must have 30.

thank you I will appreciate it

here some codes:

```
 private void showListViewData() {

    String z = "";
    String zQN = "Nu";
    String zPL = "Pl";  
    String zTR = "Tr";

    int x = Integer.parseInt(inJugada.getText().toString());
    int y = Integer.parseInt(inValor.getText().toString());

    String s = Integer.toString(x); 

    inJugada.setText(s);

    inValor.setText(String.valueOf(y));

   if(s.length() == 2){
       z = zQN;

   }else if(s.length() == 4){

       z = zPL;

   }else if(s.length() == 6){
       z = zTR;
   }

    for(int i=0; i<mData.size(); i++)
        mData.get(i);

    mData.add(new Data(z, x, y));
    Collections.sort(mData);
    Collections.synchronizedCollection(mData);

    // add new data to list and refresh
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to delete item whit ontouch, or click you will need adapter and onClick. I have list of arrays where i set the different variables "ArrayList items". Every time i get the variable i put it in this "items", then whit adapter i display in list view and on click i can make what ever i want whit item[i].

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row, items);
    ListView myList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
    myList.setAdapter(adapter);
    myList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            File f = new File(path.get(arg2));

            //your delete code here for clicked item
    }});
```

then you can call a method to calculate your variables whit simple for method.